# Why is my font not found?

Tags: java, libgdx

Trying to follow this tutorial with using toasts in LIBGDX:

[Libgdx - notification popup (something like Toast) - on both Desktop and Android](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124441/libgdx-notification-popup-something-like-toast-on-both-desktop-and-android)

But i get this error when compiling:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont registered with name: font-export.fnt
```

But i have the font in my skin folder with my skin i already use, meaning that the directory is found. I also tried skin/font

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont registered with name: skin/font-export.fnt
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
@Override
public void create() {
    sb = new SpriteBatch();
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    hudCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    hudCam.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    gsm = new GameStateManager(this);

    Skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/glassy-ui.json"));
    BitmapFont font = Skin.getFont("skin/font-export.fnt");
    toastFactory = new Toast.ToastFactory.Builder()
            .font(font)
            .build();
}
```

The directiory looks like this:

[image: directory]

Comment: Well, under what name is the font-export.fnt in your glass-ui.json registered?